# Real numbers as element of a universe

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**defn.** A universe is a set $U$ such that:

1. $x\in u\in U\Rightarrow x\in U$
2. $u\in U$ and $v\in U$ imply $\left\{u,v\right\}, \langle u,v\rangle, u\times v\in U$
3. $x\in U\Rightarrow \mathcal{P}(x)$ and $\cup x\in U$
4. $\omega\in U$
5. if $f:x\longrightarrow y$ is a surjective mapping with $x\in U$ and $y\subseteq U$ then $y\in U$

Questions:

1) is the set $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers an element of $U$?

2) if yes, how can be proved?

Comment: I should start with proving that $\mathbb Z\in U$ and $\mathbb Q\in U$. Can you do that?

Comment: @drhab yes, since they are numerable, I suppose...

Comment: What does the fourth axiom or condition mean? What is $\;\omega\;$ ?

Comment: @Joanpemo set of natural numbers, i.e. $\{0,1,\dots\}$ where $0=\varnothing$ and $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$

Comment: @Joanpemo natural numbers

Comment: @drhab Thank you. I've seen that before but with respect to ordinal numbers. Didn't think this time it was related.

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni Thank you.

Comment: The real numbers can be looked at as subsets of $\mathbb Q$ (Dedekind-cuts), so they will belong to $U$ as well. Next step is now to prove that the set of real numbers belongs to $U$.

Comment: Proving that $\mathbb R \in U$ is trivial, **once** you actually defined $\mathbb R$ in a sensible way. One the other hand, if you don't provide us with your definition of $\mathbb R$, we cannot possibly answer this question.

Comment: @drhab ok, so I might say: $\mathbb{Q}$ is in $U$, the parts of $\mathbb{Q}$ is in $U$, any subset of elements of $U$ is in $U$, so $\mathbb{R}$ is in $U$.

Comment: We reached at $\mathbb R\subset U$ but that on its own does not allow the conclusion that $R\in U$ (if it would then also $U\in U$ which is not the case I presume). @Stefan can you provide an answer if the reals are defined as [Dedekind-cuts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_cut)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me outline a proof. As previously stated in a comment, the only nontrivial part is to actually define what $\Bbb R$ is. In set theory, it is common to just let $\Bbb R := \mathcal P(\omega)$ and in this case, we immediately have that $\Bbb R \in U$. However, this definition is not very common amongst non-set theorists, and I shall therefore outline a different approach, using Dedekind cuts (as drhab suggested).

First of all, let us define $\Bbb Z := \{ (a,b) \in \omega \times \omega \mid a = 0 \vee b = 0 \}$. We may think of $(a,b)$ as the integer $a-b$. Usually, the part "$a = 0 \vee b = 0$" is omitted and one simply defines an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\omega \times \omega$ by letting $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ iff $a+d = c+b$ (which in our indented interpretation just means that $a-b = c-d$. However, we can't write this down until we actually defined $-$. Note that in contrast $+$ is defined, as the usual ordinal addition.)

Clearly $\Bbb Z \subseteq \omega \times \omega$ and hence $\Bbb Z \in \mathcal P(\omega \times \omega)$. Since, $\omega, \omega \times \omega$ and $\mathcal P(\omega \times \omega)$ are elements of $U$, we now get that $\Bbb Z \in U$ as well, by condition 1.

Next, we define $\Bbb Q = \{ (p,q) \in \Bbb Z \times \omega \mid q \neq 0 \wedge (p,q) = 1 \}$. Here $(p,q) = 1$ means that $p$ and $q$ are coprime. I leave it to you to formalize this. (There are two cases, depending on whether $p = (a,0)$ or $p = (0,b)$ and both are trivial.) Again, one usually defines $\Bbb Q$ simply as $\Bbb Z \times (\omega \setminus \{0\})$ and takes the obvious quotient of this, as in the case of $\Bbb Z$. Repeating the argument above, we now get that $\Bbb Q \in U$.

This allows us to define $\Bbb R$: We say that $C \subseteq \Bbb Q$ is a **cut**  iff $C \not \in \{ \emptyset, \Bbb Q \}$, $C$ is downward closed, i.e. for every $p \in C$ and every $q \in \Bbb Q$ with $q < p$, we have that $q \in C$, and $C$ has no $<$-maximal element. (Note that we didn't define the order $(\Bbb Q; <)$ and we actually don't need to do this - formally. We may just work with our intuitive notion of $<$ on $\Bbb Q$. It is, however, not difficult to define $<$ as a set and to show that ${<} \in U$.) We now let $\Bbb R := \{ C \subseteq \Bbb Q \mid C \text{ is a cut} \}$.Our intended interpretation is that $C$ represents that unique real $x$ such that $\{ y \in \Bbb Q \mid y < x \} = C$. Since $\mathbb R \in \mathcal P(\mathcal P(\Bbb Q))$ and $\Bbb Q \in U$, we may apply condition 1 and 3 to conlude that $\Bbb R \in U$.

So far, we only defined a set $\Bbb R$ and it is not entirely obvious that this set has anything in common with our intuitive definition of $\Bbb R$. It is however not difficult to define sets $+, {\,\cdot\,}, {<} \in U$ such that $(\Bbb R, +, {\,\cdot\,}, {<}) \in U$ is provably isomorphic to our intuitive notion of $\Bbb R$ in the sense that $(\Bbb R, +, {\,\cdot\,}, {<})$ is a complete, totally ordered field.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. $\Bbb R$ is just the quotient forcing when you factor $\Bbb P$ to a two step iteration, $\Bbb Q\ast\dot{\Bbb R}$. :-D

Comment: @Asaf Actually, I changed my mind: $\Bbb R$ is definitively the RCS limit of some iterated forcing, all of whose associated forcing names are $\dot {\Bbb R}$'s.

Comment: Now, when you say RCS iteration. Do you mean Shelah's version or the Donder-Fuchs version?

Comment: @Asaf $\Bbb R$ deserves Shelah's original notion - reflecting its promising and rich nature.

Comment: Why (in defining $\Bbb Z$ the usual way) do we need $-$ to write down $(a,b)\sim (c,d)\iff a+d=c+b$? This *does* use only $+$. - In contrast, idon't we need $-$ in order to define $+$ for $\{\,(a,b)\in\omega\times\omega\mid a=0\lor b=0\,\}$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen We don't need $-$ to define $\sim$. What I tried to say is that we (intuitively) want to define $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$ iff $a - b = c -d$ and that, we cannot do formally, since we didn't define $-$, i.e we didn't say what we mean by something like $5 - 7$. In fact, I intend to define $5-7 := (0,2)$.

Comment: Shouldn't we forbid $\emptyset,\mathbb{Q}$ from being cuts?

Comment: @chi Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it depends on what *are* the real numbers for you. Set theory and logic are very implementation agnostic when it comes to "everyday mathematics". Nobody cares what *is* the set $1_\Bbb R$, just that we can find a construct in which this set exists and behave as expected.

So for the sake of argument, let's take the usual construction:

1. The natural numbers are the finite von Neumann ordinals.
2. The integers are equivalence classes of natural numbers.
3. The rational numbers are equivalence classes of integers.
4. The real numbers are non-empty proper initial segments of the rational numbers.

So by assumption $\omega\in U$, so the natural numbers are there. Therefore the power set of $\omega$ is there, so the set of equivalence classes defining $\Bbb Z$ is there, similarly we get $\Bbb Q$ there, and finally we get $\Bbb R$.

So yes. A universe also contains the set of all the real numbers. But in reality we can say a lot more.

> **Theorem.** If $U$ is a universe, then there exists a strongly inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$ such that $U=V_\kappa$. Moreover $U$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$. (Where $V_\kappa$ is the $\kappa$th stage of the von Neumann hierarchy.)

This is not a very difficult proof, and essentially was proved by Zermelo in the 1930's. But it shows that a universe is *really* big.

Comment: "Nobody cares what is the set $1_{\Bbb R}$, just that we can find a construct in which this set exists and behave as expected." Not even set theorists do, see Asaf's blogpost: [Don't worry about it](http://karagila.org/2015/dont-worry-about-it/)

Comment: Admittedly, the downvote is not clear to me. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{Z}$ is usually constructed is such a way that its elements
form a partition of $\omega\times\omega$.

So $\mathbb{Z}\subset\wp\left(\omega\times\omega\right)$ hence $\mathbb{Z}\in\wp\left(\wp\left(\omega\times\omega\right)\right)\in U$
and consequently $\mathbb{Z}\in U$.

$\mathbb{Q}$ is usually constructed is such a way that its elements
are disjoint subsets $\mathbb{Z}\times\left(\omega-\left\{ 0\right\} \right)$.

As above we find $\mathbb{Q}\in U$.

$\mathbb{R}$ can be constructed is such a way that its elements are
subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$.

So $\mathbb{R}\subset\wp\left(\mathbb{Q}\right)$ hence $\mathbb{R}\in\wp\left(\wp\left(\mathbb{Q}\right)\right)\in U$
and consequently $\mathbb{R}\in U$.